# Rails database creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run the command `rake db:create`
I get the following message:

```
Couldn't create database for {"password"=>"secret1", "username"=>"root", "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"zooz_development", "encoding"=>"utf8", "port"=>3307,
"adapter"=>"mysql"}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci (if you set the c
harset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

I am working on win7
mysql is working on the port 3307
I have installed mysql gem
and this is my database.yml file:

```
    development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: zooz_development
  username: root
  password: secret1
  port: 3307
  host: localhost




# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: chmaysa_test
  username: root
  password: secret1
  port: 3307
  host: localhost


production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: zooz_development
  username: root
  password: secret1
  port: 3307
  host: localhost
```

Comment: can you connect the database using listed privileges? you can always do this by **rails db**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

add this to you Gemfile:
`gem 'mysql2'`

and change your adapter from `mysql` to `mysql2`